# How to reload my view in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, view, reload

I have a imageView embedded in a scrollView. The imageView needs to be downloaded from the Internet (through flickr api), so I add a thread to handle this. But what am I supposed to do after I finished downloading the image? How can I reload my imageView?Here's my code.

In fact, it is working fine. but the imageView's size is (0, 0). How can I fix that?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (!self.myImage)
    {
        UIActivityIndicatorView* spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        [spinner startAnimating];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:spinner];
        dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("flickr downloader (photo)", NULL);
        dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
            NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[FlickrFetcher urlForPhoto:self.photo format:FlickrPhotoFormatLarge]];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                [self.imageView setImage:self.myImage];
                [self viewDidLoad];
                [self viewWillAppear:NO];
                NSLog(@"imageViewSet!");
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
            });
        });    
        dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
    }
    else
    {
        NSString* imageTitle;
        if ([[self.photo objectForKey:@"title"] length] > 0)
            imageTitle = [self.photo objectForKey:@"title"];
        else if ([[self.photo valueForKeyPath:@"description._content"] length] > 0)
            imageTitle = [self.photo valueForKeyPath:@"description._content"];
        else imageTitle = @"Unknown";
        [[self navigationItem] setTitle:imageTitle];
        self.scrollView.delegate = self;
        self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.image.size;
    }
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imageView;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    double scale = self.imageView.bounds.size.width * 1.0 / self.myImage.size.width;
    if (scale > self.imageView.bounds.size.height * 1.0 / self.myImage.size.height)
        scale = self.imageView.bounds.size.height * 1.0 / self.myImage.size.height;
    NSLog(@"imgview%g, %g",self.imageView.bounds.size.width, self.imageView.bounds.size.height);
    NSLog(@"img%g, %g",self.myImage.size.width, self.myImage.size.height);
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.image.size.width, self.imageView.image.size.height);
    [self.scrollView setZoomScale:scale];
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you comment out `dispatch_release(downloadQueue);`? I think you are releasing the dispatch queue before the block gets executed.

Comment: tried that. still not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is to call:

```
[self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Edited to Add:

I just realized you said the image view is still (0,0). From [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) :

> Setting the image property does not change the size of a UIImageView.
>   Call sizeToFit to adjust the size of the view to match the image.

Comment: I tried that. I replaced [self viewWillAppear:NO]; with [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay]; but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is anything written to the console? Also, are you sure it's executing that line? Can you stop on it in the debugger?

Comment: 2012-03-24 14:13:49.451 TopPlaces[1511:f803] imgview320, 367
2012-03-24 14:13:49.452 TopPlaces[1511:f803] img0, 0

Comment: it is executing because i got a spinning wheel on the top right.

Comment: in fact my problem is that my view size is strange. the image view is of the size(0,0).